# Strange printf behavior after SIGINT handling

Tags: c, shell, printf, signals

I am making a very primitive shell using C. The prompt prints correctly and command outputs are printed correctly after entering a command. The issues arise after I do the "run" command which essentially calls execve on a user inputted executable. I made it so that if the user presses Ctrl-C (SIGINT), the parent will not die, and the child (the one running the execve'd program) gets interrupted. This works, and control is given back to the parent, but the printing of the prompt breaks after it. It can be seen when running "ls" or any other execve syscalls.

#### INTENDED OUTPUT

```
DOGsh:-$ run /bin/cat
This is cat just repeating what I say.
This is cat just repeating what I say.
Okay, I will do Ctrl-C to send SIGINT to parent and child. Parent will doNothing and child will act normally.
Okay, I will do Ctrl-C to send SIGINT to parent and child. Parent will doNothing and child will act normally.
^C
DOGsh:-$ echo "Now watch what happens when I execve('/bin/ls')..."
Now watch what happens when I execve('/bin/ls')...
DOGsh:-$ run /bin/ls
commands.c  commands.h commands.o  help.txt  main.c  main.o  makefile  readinput.c  readinput.h  readinput.o  task2  utils.c  utils.h  utils.o
DOGsh:-$
```

#### ACTUAL OUTPUT

```
DOGsh:-$ run /bin/cat
This is cat just repeating what I say.
This is cat just repeating what I say.
Okay, I will do Ctrl-C to send SIGINT to parent and child. Parent will doNothing and child will act normally.
Okay, I will do Ctrl-C to send SIGINT to parent and child. Parent will doNothing and child will act normally.
^C
DOGsh:-$ echo "Now watch what happens when I execve('/bin/ls')..."
Now watch what happens when I execve('/bin/ls')...
DOGsh:-$ run /bin/ls
/* Note the gap here and the printing of the output after the shell prompt. */
DOGsh:-$ commands.c  commands.h commands.o  help.txt  main.c  main.o  makefile  readinput.c  readinput.h  readinput.o  task2  utils.c  utils.h  utils.o
// Here it's waiting for my next command but the prompt is missing...
[-] Unknown command.  // Entering an empty command comes up with this error message.
DOGsh:-$  // Oh great, it's back...
```

#### RUN FUNCTION

```
pid_t run_pid;  // Global var of the child pid.

int run(CommandStruct *cmd_struct) {
    char *arg_str = cmd_struct->arg_str;  // The path of the executable
    char *args[2] = {arg_str, NULL};  // *argv[] for the executable

    signal(SIGINT, doNothing);  // The parent should ignore the SIGINT.
    run_pid = fork();

    if (run_pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else {
        execve(arg_str, args, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n");
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);  // Reset the handler for parent.

    return 0;
}

void doNothing(int sig) {
    return;
}
```

#### MAIN FUNCTION

```
/* Only relevant parts included */
int main() {
    char raw_cmd[BUF_SIZE];
    char install_dir[BUF_SIZE];
    CommandStruct *cmd_struct;  // A struct with the command name and its args.
    Commands cmd;  // Enum with command names. Used for easier decision making.

    // ...

    while (1) {
        printf("\033[1;31mDOG\033[1;30msh:-$\033[0;37m ");  // Coloured prompt.
        fgets(raw_cmd, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
        cmd_struct = getCommandStruct(raw_cmd);
        cmd = getCommandFromCommandStruct(cmd_struct);

        switch (cmd) {
            case CLEAR:
                clear();
                break;
            // ...
            case RUN:
                run(cmd_struct);  // Run function
                break;
        }

        free((void*) cmd_struct);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: MCVE**
I created something similar that recreates the problem I have, just keep hitting enter when you encounter the getchar I put in the loop to act as breakpoints.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct CommandStruct {
    char cmd[BUF_SIZE];
    char arg_str[BUF_SIZE];
} CommandStruct;

pid_t run_pid;

void doNothing(int sig) {
    return;
}

int run(CommandStruct *cmd_struct) {
    char *arg_str = cmd_struct->arg_str;
    char *args[2] = {arg_str, NULL};

    signal(SIGINT, doNothing);
    run_pid = fork();

    if (run_pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else {
        execve(arg_str, args, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    CommandStruct cmd_struct;
    strcpy(cmd_struct.cmd, "run");
    strcpy(cmd_struct.arg_str, "/bin/cat");

    while (1) {
        printf("\033[1;31mDOG\033[1;30msh:-$\033[0;37m ");
        getchar();  // Waiting to continue.

        run(&cmd_struct);

        printf("\033[1;31mDOG\033[1;30msh:-$\033[0;37m ");
        getchar();  // Waiting to continue.

        strcpy(cmd_struct.arg_str, "/bin/ls");

        run(&cmd_struct);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I presume you're allocating space for `cmd_struct`? Looks like you could just keep it in automatic storage.

Comment: I malloced space for a cmd_struct. Does that really change anything?

Comment: The prompt isn't missing; it simply appears before the output of the `ls` command (`DOGsh:-$ commands.c  …`).  That's not uncommon.  You should probably be using `sigaction()` rather than `signal()`, if only because it doesn't reset the signal handler.  However, that's tangential to the behaviour.  You might also note that if you fail to fork, your parent process arranges to `execve()` the command you specified, thereby committing suicide.  You should probably explicitly handle 'failure to fork'.

Comment: It would be sensible to error check the `wait()`: `int status, corpse; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) { printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status); if (corpse == run_pid) break; }` or something similar, especially while debugging.  You might want to think about resetting `run_pid` (to 0 or -1) when the child is known to have exited.

Comment: However, neither of those previous comments fully explains what you're seeing. It isn't obvious why your shell isn't waiting for `ls` to complete before it prints its prompt. Making sure you have copious error messages (at least while you're debugging your shell) will make life easier.  Check every system call that can fail and that you can recover from (`close()` is one of the few you can't do anything much about — you don't know whether the file descriptor is open or closed if the close operation fails). It would be easier if we had an MCVE ([MCVE]) to work with — 'compilable' being the key.